# Build dynamic associative array from simple array in php

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have an array as given below

```
$arr = ['Product', 'Category', 'Rule'];
```

This can be a **dynamic array** meaning it can sometimes have between 1-5 elements inside it and its value can change.
How can we create an array as given below from the above one in a **dynamic manner**.

```
$json['Product']['Category']['Rule'] = 'fixed';
```

Simply put am just trying to make a multidimensional array from the values I get from the $arr.

Comment: Where did the `'fixed'` value come from?

Comment: @BadHorsie: It's just a static. But in code i will have some data to be assigned to it.
This is just to keep things simple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function should do it.

```
function nestArray($arr, $value) {
    if (!count($arr)) {
        return $value;
    }
    foreach (array_reverse($arr) as $key) {
        $new = [$key => $value];
        $value = $new;
    }
    return $new;
}
```

**Example**

```
$arr = ['Product', 'Category', 'Rule'];
$nested = nestArray($arr, 'fixed');
print_r($nested);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [Product] => Array
        (
            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [Rule] => fixed
                )

        )

)
```